# Developing with backbone.js, how can I detect when multiple users(browsers) attempt to update?

Tags: rest, backbone.js

I am very new to backbone.js (and MVC with javascript), and while reading several resources about backbone.js to adopt it in my project, I now have a question: how can I detect when multiple users(browsers) attempt to update? (and prevent it?)

My project is a tool for editing surveys/polls for users who want to create and distribute their own surveys. So far, my web app maintains a list of edit-commands fired by browser, sends it to the server, and the server does batch update.

What I did was, each survey maintains a version number and browser must request update with that version number, and if the request's version number does not match with the one in the server, the request fails and the user must reload his page (you know, implementing concurrent editing is not easy for everyone). Of course, when the browser's update was successful, it gets new version number from the server as ajax response, and one browser can request update to server only when its past update request is done.

Now, I am interested in RESTful APIs and MV* patterns, but having a hard time to solve this issue. What is the best / common approach for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a common trick instead of using versions, use TIMESTAMPS in your DB and then try to UPDATE WHERE timestamp = model.timestamp. If it returns zero result count - use appropriate HTTP 409 (conflict) response and ask the user to update the page in save() error callback. You can even use the local storage to merge changes, and compare the non-equivalent side by side.